# Speed up access to a MySQL database using Perl and DBI

Tags: perl, caching

I am new to Perl, and am looking to cache the results of a Perl program to relieve database server load.

I am thinking to implement a file cache for this (but not server-based caching techniques like memcached) or maybe if you recommend whatever is better.

I want the results to be stored in a file (once it is retrieved from the database) and next time, before querying the database, the cache file is checked for the same parameters.

I was thinking to make a CSV file but seems it is more complicated.

This program does checking an IP of user, if IP exists in database, user is given access.

```
use DBI;
use DBD::mysql;

require 'shellwords.pl';

$| = 1;

my $database = "xxxx";
my $user     = "xxxx";
my $pass     = "xxxx";
my $host     = "xxx.xxx.xx.xx";

sub valid() {

  $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:$db:$host:3306", $user, $pass)
      or die $DBI::errstr;

  my $sql = "SELECT * FROM authip WHERE ips = '$ip'";
  my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
  $sth->execute()
      or die $dbh->errstr;
  my $result = eval { $sth->fetchrow_arrayref->[0] };
}

while (<>) {

  ($ip) = &shellwords;

  if (&valid($result)) {
    print "OK";
  }
  else {
    print "ERR";
  }
}
```

Comment: Where have you learned Perl from? Your coding style is from version 4 of Perl 5. Version 6 was released in March 2000

Comment: I would suggest you consider the performance implications of what going on here as well.  It's good to reduce server load, obviously.  However, storing all of the results in a CSV file that needs to be searched to get the cached result seems like you'll be just shifting the problem elsewhere instead of solving it.  Is there a way instead to perform batched queries to the database?  Is there an index on the ips column?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear, as you don't say what it is that you want to accelerate, or why.

The example code that you show is flawed, as follows

- You *must always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of *every* Perl program that you write. You will also need to declare every variable that you use, which you seem to be doing fine
- Using `require` to include some external code is a bit clunky, and it is better to write a proper module - perhaps using [`Exporter`](https://metacpan.org/module/Exporter) to make specific subroutines available to the calling code
- It is much more expressive to replace `$|=1` with `STDOUT->autoflush`, which works fine if you have done `use IO::Handle`. Every version of Perl since 14 has `IO::File` required by default, so you don't even need to write the `use`
- *Never* write Perl subroutines with a prototype. That is the part that expresses what parameters the subroutine expects. In your case you have `sub valid() { ... }`, which insists that `valid` will take no parameters; yet you call it later with `if (&valid($result)) { ... }`
- *Never* use `&` to call a subroutine. Something like `&shellwords` should be used only when you are treating the subroutine as data, for instance to get a subroutine reference like this

  ```
  my $sub = \&shellwords
  my ($ip) = $sub->();
  ```

  Amongst other things, the `&` prefix has the effect of ignoring any subroutine prototypes. That is why, even though you defined `valid` to have no parameters, you may have seen it work because you called it with `&valid($result)`.

  Although in this case two wrongs seem to work, they definitely don't make a right!

After this is a number of semantic problems.

You are hoping to speed up your software by caching results, yet your `valid` subroutine does `connect`, `prepare`, `execute` every time it is called. It also *interpolates* the value of `$ip` into the SQL statement to be executed: something that is poisonous on public networks, and so easy to avoid that you should invest in using a placeholder style everywhere. It will give you better security and make your code much more readable and maintainable.

I'm not sure why you're using `eval` around the `fetchrow_arrayref` call. It will kill the program only if you choose to index it as an array without checking its value.

Here is a refactoring of the code you show. Maybe it doesn't need a caching policy at all?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.014;

use DBI;

use ShellWords qw/ shellwords /;

STDOUT->autoflush;

my $host     = 'xxx.xxx.xx.xx';
my $database = 'xxxx';
my $user     = 'xxxx';
my $pass     = 'xxxx';

my $dbh = DBI->connect(
    "DBI:mysql:$db:$host:3306",
    $user,
    $pass
) or die $DBI::errstr;

my $select = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM authip WHERE ips = ?');

while (<>) {

  my ($ip)     = shellwords;
  my $is_valid = valid($ip);

  print $is_valid ? "OK\n" : "ERR\n";
}

sub valid {
  my ($ip) = @_;

  $select->execute($ip) or die $dbh->errstr;
  $sth->fetchrow_arrayref;
}
```

I hope it's clear that I have assumed `shellwords.pl` will be rewritten properly as a module in `ShellWords.pm`. Whatever is inside `shellwords.pl` it is using the values of many variables that are available only in the right context and are not passed by parameter.

I hope this helps. Despite not answering your question directly I think I have done all I can to suggest a solution. Please explain more if my intuition is off the mark.

Comment: @friedo: The *language* is Perl 5. The *version* is 14. Neither *"Perl 4"* nor *"Perl 6"* are valid production languages now, and anyone who means either of those will say so explicitly. So in a vacuum *"Perl"* means *"Perl 5"*, and after that we need only to say which version we're talking about

Comment: nobody in the world knows what the hell you're talking about when you say "Perl version 14." Clarity does not necessarily result from pedantry.

Comment: @friedo: What I'm talking about will never matter to those who can't extrapolate from *Perl v14*. *Perl 6* has taken a seat where *Perl 5* would have gone and it refuses to budge, while at the same time it will not publish. So what the world knows as **Perl** is *Perl 5* and, depending on Larry's decisions, will be *Perl 5* forever until version 999 and beyond.

Comment: @friedo: Of course, downvoting my answer would be a great way to show your displeasure with the way I refer to Perl versions. Why don't you go ahead and do that?